# jQuery Mobile Multi-Page-method specified capture event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile  Multi-Page-method specified capture event

html:sub1.html , sub2.html , sub3.html  + js:each_page.js

sub1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="../../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="each_page.js" ></script>
<script>
function init(){
        now = new Date();
        $('#p1_content').html("John's event..."+ now.getMinutes() +":"+ now.getSeconds() );
}
function fun_a(){}
function fun_b(){}
</script>
<script src="../../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" ></script>
</head><BODY>
<div data-role=page id='p_sub1'>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="x" data-position="fixed" >
        <a data-role="button" id="prv" data-icon="false" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1 id="title_name"> page_x </h1>
  </div>

 <div data-role="content" id="p1_content"> <h3>sub[1]</h3> </div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="sub1.html" ><img src="../../images/m1.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="sub2.html" ><img src="../../images/m2.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="sub3.html" ><img src="../../images/m3.png"/></a></li>
          </ul></div>
        </div>
</div></BODY></HTML>
```

sub2.html

```
...
    <script>
    function init(){
            now = new Date();
            $('#p1_content').html("Mary ....."+ now.getMinutes() +":"+ now.getSeconds() );
    }
    function fun_ii(){}
    function fun_jjj(){}
    </script>
...
```

each_page.js

```
$(function() {
    var selector = ':jqmData(role=page)';
    $('body').on('pageinit', selector, function(e, data) {
        // initialize page
        var $page = $(this);
        var now = new Date();
        $('#'+$page.attr('id') +' #title_name').html(""+ $page.attr('id') +"--- now:"+ now.getMinutes() +":"+ now.getSeconds()  );
        //alert( $page.attr('id')  );
    }).on('pagebeforeshow', selector, function(e, data) {
        // showpage
        var $page = $(this);
        init();
    });

});
```

What to call individual pages init ()

Or other methods ?!

Because a lot of pages, has a different javascript method

Above only almost called single

mobileinit touch sub1.html (v.sub1.html:init() ; x.sub2.html:init())